# Insert Contact Icons + Text in CV sidebar

Tags: latex

I am relying on the following template for my CV on LaTeX:

https://olivierpieters.be/blog/2017/10/02/designing-a-cv-in-latex-part-2

I am now a little blocked at the Contact Section, which I started as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
\matrix[
column1/.style={anchor=center,contactIcon},
column2/.style={anchor=west, align=left,contactText},
column sep=5pt](Contact){
\node{\faMapMarker};
&\node{xxx};};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The end goal should be to have the icon on the left and text on the right. However it does not work for me, showing the following error message corresponding to the final part of the code:

```
"!Missing } inserted. <inserted text>}\end{tikzpicture}"
"!Missing \cr inserted. <inserted text>\cr\end{tikzpicture}"
"!Misplaced \cr.<inserted text>\cr\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you may be missing two backslashes at the end of your second to last line of code. 

`&\node{xxx};\ \ };`